# Construct SimplicialLLT object from provided L matrix

Tags: eigen

I performed LLT factorization of a sparse matrix (SimplicialLLT) and modified the L matrix to Lmod (**EDIT**: I made a copy of the matrix with some modifications). I would like to construct a new SimplicialLLT object from this modified matrix Lmod so that I can directly use it to obtain a solution of system (Lmod*Lmod')x = B. Is this somehow possible in Eigen? Here is a short code example:

```cpp
    #include <iostream>
    #include <Eigen/Dense>
    #include <Eigen/Sparse>
    
    using namespace Eigen;
    using namespace std;
    
    int main()
    {
    // Initial system A0 x0 = B
        // Create dense matrix first
        MatrixXd A0dense(5, 5);
        A0dense << 1,0,0,0,0,0,2,-1,0,0,0,-1,2,-1,0,0,0,-1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1;
    
        // Convert it to sparse
        SparseMatrix<double> A0;
        A0 = A0dense.sparseView();
    
        // Create LLT decomposition od A0
        SimplicialLLT<SparseMatrix<double>, Lower, NaturalOrdering<int>> LLTofA0(A0); 
    
        // Extract the L matrix
        SparseMatrix<double> L0 = LLTofA0.matrixL();
        cout << "L0 =" << endl << L0 << endl;
    
        // RHS vector B
        VectorXd B(5);
        B << 0, 0, 0, 1, 1;
    
    // Create a copy of L0 with some modifications
        vector<Triplet<double>> Triplets; // Vector of triplets
        for (int k = 0; k < L0.outerSize(); ++k)
        {
            for (SparseMatrix<double>::InnerIterator it(L0, k); it; ++it) // Iterate over nonzero entries of L0
            {
                if (it.col() != 2) 
                {
                    // If the column is unequal to 2, store the location and value
                    Triplet<double> T(it.row(), it.col(), it.value());
                    Triplets.push_back(T); 
                }
                
            }
        }
    
        // Create modified Lmod matrix from the stored triplets
        SparseMatrix<double> Lmod(L0.outerSize(), L0.outerSize());
        Lmod.setFromTriplets(Triplets.begin(), Triplets.end()); 
        cout << "Lmod =" << endl << Lmod << endl;
    
    // Now I want to solve different system (Lmod*Lmod') x = B and use the matrix Lmod for it
    
    }
```

Comment: Could you give a bit more context? How did you modify the L matrix? I've only worked with SparseLU up to now and am not aware that you can modify the triangular matrices.
A minimal working example would be good.

Comment: @Eike Sure, I edited the question. When I said I modified the L matrix a meant I created a copy with some modifications.

Comment: I see. Not that I am any kind of expert on this but I don't think there is a way to supply the L matrix to SimplicalCholesky. Maybe its possible to make a `TriangularView` of `Lmod` and use its `solveInPlace`? Not sure about that.

Comment: Also isn't there also a permutation you must take in account? At least for SparseLU there is one.

Comment: @Eike Yes, the option with `TriangularView` and `solveInPlace` is what I used in the end, but thanks for the help. By adding the option `NaturalOrdering<int>` the permutation matrix is set to identity, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: Glad you could work it out. Would be cool if you could answer your question, so people can find a solution!